# Mysql how to get parent and all child for given ID?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have two table (category, product) as below:

Category Table:

```
cid name parent
1  items Null
2    A    1
3    aa   2
4    ab   2
5    ac   2
6    B    1
7    ba   5
8    bb   5
9    bc   5
10   C    1
11   ca   9
12   cb   9
13   cc   9
```

Product Table:

```
pid  cid  pname
1     2   p1
2     3   p2
3     4   p3
4     4   p4
5     5   p5
6     5   p6
```

Here  I want to get all parent and child products for a particular parent. Here I have `cid = 2`, then I need all the products to `cid=2` and its child.

Here I tried it something like this, but not sure how to join `product` table with this query:

```
select  cid,
        name,
        parent
from    (select * from categories
         order by parent, cid) categories,
        (select @pv := '2') initialisation
where   find_in_set(parent, @pv) > 0
and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', cid)
```

**UPDATES:** 
DB Model

[image]

Can anybody help me out? 
Thank you.

Comment: Post expected o/p?

Comment: I don't know why this have down vote.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja, Here I want to get all parent and child products from product table for a particular parent category id. 
Eg: assume I have `cid=2` then I need `p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6` from product table

Comment: Its not really obvious from the table definations what is a parent or child and what fields between the two tables relate. e.g. is cid a category id or a child id? An example that includes all outputs doesn't clarify it that much.

Comment: @danblack it is `cid`

Comment: @danblack I updated question with DB model. pls check it

Comment: what's a parent? What's a child? Are these totally within category. Some more examples would help. A broken SQL example doesn't clarify much. Are you expecting parents of parents? and children of children? If so MySQL-8.0 or MariaDB-10.2+ is needed for recursive CTEs to get your answer.

Comment: @danblack exactly my point. How  come cid 2 in your above data has all products. Post relevant data not explanation. Relevant data is self explanatory at times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it should be noted that your query won't give you the root category, only its children. So you need to add a `UNION` to it to include the root category. Secondly you don't need a subquery for the recursive part, you can do the ordering in the query directly. You can then use that query as a derived table and `JOIN` it to the `products` table:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT 2 AS cid
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT  cid
       FROM categories
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT @pv := '2') initialisation
       WHERE   find_in_set(parent, @pv) > 0
         AND   @pv := concat(@pv, ',', cid)
       ORDER BY parent, cid)
      ) c
JOIN products p ON p.cid = c.cid
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
cid     pid     cid     pname
2       1       2       p1
3       2       3       p2
4       3       4       p3
4       4       4       p4
5       5       5       p5
5       6       5       p6
```

You might want just a list of product names, in which case you can replace `*` in the outer query with e.g. `GROUP_CONCAT(p.pname) AS products` and get the result:

```
products
p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hpheuKtHJ5U2445GrKozke/1)

To also get the category name, you must `SELECT` that in the inner query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT cid, name
      FROM categories
      WHERE cid = 2
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT  cid, name
       FROM categories
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT @pv := '2') initialisation
       WHERE   find_in_set(parent, @pv) > 0
         AND   @pv := concat(@pv, ',', cid)
       ORDER BY parent, cid)
      ) c
JOIN products p ON p.cid = c.cid
```

Output:

```
cid     name    pid     cid     pname
2       A       1       2       p1
3       aa      2       3       p2
4       ab      3       4       p3
4       ab      4       4       p4
5       ac      5       5       p5
5       ac      6       5       p6
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hpheuKtHJ5U2445GrKozke/2)

Comment: great mate u understood what the OP meant by the above query and data. I wonder if Ill be able to catch the same.

Comment: @Nick This is actually what I needed. Thank you very much. One question how I get category name along with this select?

Comment: I tried it changing outer query as this `SELECT p.pid
      ,p.pname
      ,c.name` but its not working

Comment: @user3733831 please see my edit. I've added a query which will fetch the category name as well

Comment: Great. one more question... can we fetch specific columns instead of `*` in outer query?

Comment: @user3733831 of course. For example, you can just select `c.name` and `p.pname` if that's all you're interested in. I just chose `*` to show all the information that was available from the query.

Comment: Yes I tried it as `SELECT p.cid, p.pname,c.name` but there is an error `Query Error: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'c.name' in 'field list'`

Comment: Sorry.. it seems its my fault. Now its working perfectly. Thank you very much

Comment: @user3733831 I think you didn't use my updated query, it works fine for me too https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hpheuKtHJ5U2445GrKozke/3

Comment: Sorry @Nick, I have one more question. I need to get parent category name along with others

Comment: Sheesh! You're making me work hard! :-)  try this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hpheuKtHJ5U2445GrKozke/5

Answer (score 0):

```
select product.pname, product.cid, category.parent
  from product 
 inner join category
    on product.cid = catgeory.cid;
```

Comment: This is not what I needed

Comment: Don't worry @mamta-soni , I couldn't work out the question either. Still can't.

Comment: @danblack I updated question with DB model. pls check it